# Does the angular cli production build tree shake RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I'm attempting to find a good pattern for structuring typescript modules targeted for angular 4 consumption (Pure typescript modules like RxJS - no angular dependencies).  RxJS seems like a good library to learn from.  Does the angular 4 production build (`ng build --prod`) tree shake RxJS as it is published to NPM right now, or does RxJS need to be compiled to ES6 modules in order for the cli to be able to tree shake it?

In other words if the following is performed:

```
npm i rxjs
```

And then from an angular component:

```
import { Observable }        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }           from 'rxjs/Subject';

// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

The production build will contain only the above pieces of RxJS and not the entire RxJS library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking, while --prod builds also run limited dead code elimination via UglifyJS.

As  per https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: I updated the question a bit.  I'm asking whether RxJS, as it is currently published, supports tree shaking by the angular 4 build.

Comment: went through couple of blog post and general consensus was if you 
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; then ng build will do tree-shaking and will generate lower size bundle.

Comment: Do you have any of these links?